# Why does MySql update ignore where clause?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, where-clause

I'd like to find all rows of a table with unformatted text in a specific column and re-format it.  Update seems like the right choice for this but it fails.  For example this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
INSERT INTO `test` (name) VALUES ('jerk'),('cad'),('slouch'),('slime');
```

Running the following update to add an `!` to each name that doesn't contain it (but not names that do) ignores the where clause and always updates:

```
UPDATE test SET name = CONCAT(name, '!') WHERE LOCATE(name, '!') = 0;
```

Repeated application of this update keeps adding more **!** to the end of `name`.

What's going on here and how can I do this conditional update?

EDIT: fixed typo WHERELOCATE -> WHERE LOCATE

Comment: Swap the arguments to LOCATE.

Comment: Is there a space between WHERE and LOCATE in your query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your arguments for LOCATE are backwards. It's LOCATE(substr, str).
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_locate